# Removing \r\n in python

Tags: python

I need to remove \r\n on mylist.

```
print mylist
>>> [1, '\r\nabc   Fa              153             M   Wa 3\r\n']
```

I did

```
lst = [txt.replace("\r\n", "") for txt in mylist]
```

but I get below error

```
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'replace'
```

Comment: That is because your list contains multiple data types... `lst[0] = [1], lst[1] = ['\r\n...\r\n']`

Answer (score 4):

You can use a ternary expression to skip trying to `replace` anything that isn't a string.

```
lst = [txt.replace("\r\n", "") if isinstance(txt, str) else txt for txt in mylist]
```

Comment: Not sure I'd call the variable `txt` when the whole problem is that not all elements are strings..

Comment: @DSM neither would I, but I try to make my answers as close to the code in the question as possible.

Comment: In case `txt` may be _unicode_ text, `isinstance(txt, basestring)` fits better.

Answer (score 1):

You can just strip the data from the start and end:

```
l = [1, '\r\nabc   Fa              153             M   Wa 3\r\n']

print([x.strip() if isinstance(x, basestring ) else x for x in l ]) 
[1, 'abc   Fa              153             M   Wa 3']
```

A better solution would be to strip before you add the lines to the list if possible.

Comment: That would filter the items from the list. Not quite what OP wants, I think.

Comment: @Thrustmaster, yep missed the else

Comment: Use python 2 syntax, seems like that's what the OP is using.

Comment: It should still be `replace`, not `strip` to get the interior `\r\n`s.

Comment: @tdelaney, where do you see that?

Comment: OP is doing `txt.replace("\r\n", "")` - his example only has `\r\n` on the ends, so `strip` works, but that's only one example and would not hold true for interior new lines. `replace` would remain closer to the OPs code.

Comment: @tdelaney, well  I am guessing they are at the start and end of the strings, unless the OP states otherwise.

Comment: @ReutSharabani, what is python3 specific about it?

Answer (score 0):

Your first item is an `int` and the second is a `str`. If you are going to have a mix of types, you could use `str.strip()` in a list comprehension to handle stripping the strings.

```
>>> mylist = [1, '\r\nabc   Fa              153             M   Wa 3\r\n']
>>> mylist = [i.strip() if isinstance(i, basestring) else i for i in mylist]
>>> mylist
[1, 'abc   Fa              153             M   Wa 3']
```

Comment: `type(i) == str`?  Seems like `isinstance(i, str)` (`basestring` on python2.x...) would be much better here

Comment: @mgilson Is that just a style thing or is the former method incorrect in some cases?

Comment: both.  `type(x) == SomeType` checks that the type matches exactly.  Your filter won't strip string subclasses.  This probably isn't a _huge_ deal here since there are no other builtin string subclasses ...  However, if you change it to `isinstance(i, basestring)`, then your check will work on both `unicode` and `str` and there is no (clean) way to do that using `type(...) == ...`